# Input Argument for Histogram of Oriented Gradient function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the function given in this link [HOG](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46408-histogram-of-oriented-gradients--hog--code-using-matlab).

However, when I am writing these command in the command line :

```
image = imread('image.jpg);
hog_feature_vector(image);
```

An error like this is thrown :
"Undefined function 'hog_feature_vector' for input arguments of type 'uint8' ". Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `hog_feature_vector(im)` is not in the MATLAB search path. If you are running this from command window then go to the same folder and run the code or add the folder containing the `hog` function in the path. If you are calling this function from another `.m-file`, you can use the command `addpath(genpath('<<HOG function folder path here>>'))` at the starting of your `m-file`. If you write this command then you can call the `hog` function from anywhere.

Also, please avoid using `image` as a variable name since it also is a MATLAB command. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html).

Comment: Thank you very much @Parag S. Chandakkar.  Quick & good response :)